# Famo.us - Customizing .render() & .commit() - Will it affect 60fps and cpu performance?

Tags: famo.us

I am using Famo.us and getting to a stage where I am customising the Rendering & Commit function for some of the objects I am creating.

Since Famo.us is basically a Gaming Engine and runs at 60 frames per second, how much code is able to be placed and 'parsed' in the Render and Commit functions before it affects the 60 frames per second?

Thanks.

Mark

Comment: The answer is going to be different for each use case and depends on each condition met in the rendering. Unanswerable. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Maybe I have not explained it properly.  I appreciate there can be lots of different scenarios and as such it would depend on what is rendered  - But I am talking about the time it takes to execute the code within those functions - and whether the time taken (in executing the code) takes away from the 60fps.. If that was the case then there would be a 'limit' to the code that is executed that does not affect the 'frame rate'

Comment: This has been an outstanding issue with the current code base.  I have linked to the issue in the repository below.  Although not directly related to cpu, fps is also affected by these issues.

Comment: This and some other reasons is why I have actively stopped pursuing production development of Famo.us until mixed mode is released in a public repository in open source.

Comment: Awwwww man..... Guess I will have too also.  I have been told it will be available in June...wasn't sure if I was meant to say your answer was the solution - please let me know if not and I will update it.

Comment: Yeah, it is.  Unfortunately it does not solve anything, but lets people know why they will be limited by the current architecture with the current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Famo.us prior to Mixed mode [this has been an issue](https://github.com/Famous/famous/issues/111).

#### [Mixed Mode version](https://github.com/Famous/famous/issues/111#issuecomment-66667593)

The new version will be addressing this issue and others that affect performance.  There will be a full rewrite of the Engine in this new version.

**Note:** As of the date of this question, mixed mode has not been released to the public. Mixed mode will be allow rendering to WebGL and DOM. The current version is DOM only.

#### via [@michaelobriena](https://github.com/michaelobriena) at Famo.us [commented on Dec 11, 2014](https://github.com/Famous/famous/issues/111#issuecomment-66667593)

> We are working on this in mixed mode. This is essentially gutting our
>   entire core composition & layout layers.
>
> Things that get killed:
>
> Entity Spec Parser
>
> Things that will either change a lot or have its functionality and
>   purpose moved to other modules:
>
> Context RenderNode Surface render/commit & more
>
> Because this is such a huge overhaul, we need to take the time to
>   investigate how we can use our changes to improve the API. We are
>   really trying to codify our patterns and remove the bad habits we
>   started of subclassing our base classes, overuse of eventing, and
>   solving every problem through extra state.